# c# UWP ReadTextAsync fails at 2 time

Tags: c#, uwp, io

So i'm trying to import 2 configs from the localfolder with `Windows.Storage`. But at the second time it fails with no exception.
This is my Code:

```
public async Task<string> ImportLines(string filename)
{
            try
            {
                Windows.Storage.StorageFile importFile = await StorageFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
                string savedString = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(importFile);
                return savedString;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
             //log
            }
}
```

I call  this methode with:

```
        public async void LoadConfig()
        {

            if (File.Exists(_textDataHandler.StorageFolder.Path + @"\" + PluginsFilename))
            {
                string tmp = await _textDataHandler.ImportLines(PluginsFilename);
                Plugins = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PluginConfiguration>(tmp);

            }
            else
            {
                CreateDefaultPluginsConfiguration();
                //log
                _textDataHandler.CreateFile(_pluginsFilename);
                string export = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Plugins, Formatting.Indented);
                _textDataHandler.ExportText(_pluginsFilename, export);
                //log
            }

            if (File.Exists(_textDataHandler.StorageFolder.Path + @"\" + _settingsFilename))
            {

                string tmp = await _textDataHandler.ImportLines(Settingsfilename);
                Config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Configuration>(tmp);
                _textDataHandler.CreateFile(Config.DatabaseFilename);
            }
            else
            {

                CreateDefaultSettingsConfiguration();
                //log
                _textDataHandler.CreateFile(_settingsFilename);
                string export = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Config, Formatting.Indented);
                _textDataHandler.ExportText(_settingsFilename, export);
                //Log
            }


        }
```

If one config does not exist its fine but if both exist it fails at the second time

Comment: I do not have many bits of knowledge in this area, did you checked these samples? https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/FileAccess/cs

Answer (score 0):

If you have created async method. please avoid synchronous invoke with `GetResult`. You could add `await` key word in front of calling line.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string tmp = await ImportLines(Filename);
}
```

**Update**

Please try use `dataReader` to read file content.

```
public async Task<string> ImportLines(string filename)
{
    try
    {
        StorageFile importFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
        var buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(importFile);
        using (var dataReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer))
        {
            return dataReader.ReadString(buffer.Length);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the `await` key word before the `GetResult` but i had the same issue.

Comment: Please share your `ImportLines` method, I tested public async `Task<string> ImportLines(string filename)
{
    try
    {
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile importFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
        string savedString = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(importFile);
        return savedString;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }

}`  it works well.

Comment: Yes, but it changes nothing because it works till `ReadBufferAsync` and then it stands.